# Nginx and Apache 2

Tags: apache, nginx, networking, websocket, devops

My application deployed on apache2 in Ubuntu and I am routing it through nginx with domain name it shows me websocket error handshake error 503 service unavailable error it could  worked or not?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what you have done exactly and what you are asking about. Also tag the things you’re talking about (Apache, Nginx...) so people can find this question. But first explain the situation. At the moment we have no idea what’s happening and what the actual question is. You got an error, seems it doesn’t work, so that can’t be the question.

Comment: Commonly, nginx and apache are equivalents. Why are you using Nginx and Apache? Also show us your configurations.